# Shared Printing Problem

Tags: printing

I am using 2 PCs one installed **Windows 10** and another installed Latest Updated **Ubuntu 20LTS.**
I am using **HP LaserJet 1020Plus** Printer by Wired on Win 10 PC.
Now please tell me how to Print by my Ubuntu to my printer **wirelessly**?
I have connected my both PCs with my one Modem/Router wirelessly.